# Using Named font sizes for Button FontSize in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

With Label FontSize can be set using NameSized font, eg: Default, Small....

However, this is not valid when I try to set Button FontSize to these enum,
Is there a way to do this in Xaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Button` has its own `FontSize` property.

```
 <Button Text="Hello" />
    <Button FontSize="Medium" Text="Hello" />
```

Screenshot:

[image]